# Object translation into another object with the same data? Java

Tags: java, paypal

I am using PayPal's SOAP API which has a concrete class called AddressType.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_SOAP/

Before I can pass my shipping information to PayPal I need to translate my current shipping object which is of type Address.

Currently I am doing this inside my logic which is not pretty.

```
    AddressType shippingAddress = new AddressType();
    Address input = storedOrderDetails.getShippingDetails().getShippingAddress();
    shippingAddress.setStreet1(input.getAddressLine1());
    shippingAddress.setPostalCode(input.getPostCode());
    shippingAddress.setCityName(input.getTown());
    shippingAddress.setCountryName(input.getCountryName());
```

Is there a better way to do this, I tried casting but since the classes properties and method signatures don't match this won't work.

Any suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go for some bean-mapping frameworks such as [Orika](http://malsolo.com/blog4java/?p=465) or [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/). Both of them are good and I've done some projects with each one. Actually there are more than 20 bean mapping frameworks but I didn't try them all.

Both of them map similar properties of source and destination objects automatically out of the box, but you can map dissimilar properties in static mappings.xml files or dynamically using programming APIs.

They can do more than simple mapping, such as converting lists to maps or flatten hierarchy of objects into a simple object and so on. But I don't think you need these kind of features in your project for now.

In general, using or not using these kind of frameworks have some pros. and cons. I can tell, if these kind of type mappings are not frequent in your codes, don't make your projects complicated by using them, and do them manually as you did.

Good Luck.